# How is segwit2x different from segwit?

Tags: segregated-witness, segwit2x

Today everybody got the news about the potential segwit2x adoption. However, I am trying to understand:
while both of them based on the same segwit principals how they are different? Is it about the blocksize, signaling or is it about the implementation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**SegWit2x** is a combination of both **SegWit** and a **2MB hardfork** (to activate three months after SegWit).

**SegWit2x** uses a different 'bit' for signaling (bit 4 instead of bit 1) than **SegWit**.

**SegWit** (BIP141) is not activated at the moment because it requires **95% of the mining hashrate**, and not enough miners support **SegWit** at the moment, because some miners want a hardfork to increase the blocksize. To work around this the proposal of BIP148 allows users to force the miners to mine **SegWit** blocks by orphaning other blocks after August 1, 2017. BIP149 is a similar proposal, but will activate 11 months later. The vast majority of the core developers [prefer BIP141 but most find BIP148 and BIP149 acceptable alternatives](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Segwit_support).

**SegWit2x** differs in implementation because of the activation of the **2MB hardfork** and the lower activation threshold of **80% of the mining hashrate**. **SegWit** (BIP141/BIP148/BIP149) itself has been developed by dozens of developers for over a year, has been tested extensively and has been ready for activation for some time now. It also has been successfully activated in Litecoin already. **SegWit2x** however is being developed at the time of writing by just a few non-core developers, although **SegWit2x** aims to be 'minimalistic', some people still consider this a risk because there is only a few months for development and only 2 weeks for testing.

At the time of writing the percentage of blocks signaling support for **SegWit2x** is at **78% of the mining hashrate**: 
https://blockchain.info/charts/nya-support

Comment: +1 While I feel that this answer is accurate, it could be improved by adding corroborating evidence for "some miners want a hardfork", "tested extensively", and "some people still consider this a risk".

Comment: bit 4 of version?

Comment: @SigTouri: Bit 4 of the version bits. See [What are version bits?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/39216/5406)

Comment: So which BIP is SegWit 2x?

Comment: @Josh SegWit2x is BIP91 which forces signaling for BIP141 but only 80% is required (versus 95%), combined with BIP102 - a hard fork to 2MB to happen 144*90 blocks after SegWit activates

Comment: Is my understanding correct? Segwit was activated on **August 23rd 2017** [c.f. article from CoinDesk](https://www.coindesk.com/50-blocks-segwit-bitcoins-coming-upgrade-blockchain-game-changer/), and the switch to 2MB will happen at the end of November [c.f. article from Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurashin/2017/07/25/why-november-will-be-the-real-test-for-bitcoin/#3b1f60734c91)