# SegWit 2x what is it really?

Tags: segregated-witness, segwit2x

SegWit 2x anounced not so long time ago.

Is it true, that SegWit2x take more network traffic and disk space?

So what are the advantages of it's integration?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54728/516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segwit2x will have a larger block size. This means that the amount of data in a block will be larger, which implies that more data is being transferred and stored for each block. So yes, it will require more bandwidth and disk space.

Comment: what are the advantages of it's integration?

Comment: "integration"? in what?

Comment: i mean integration of additional data in blockchain. is it so necessary for to add this data?

Comment: @PieterWuille ?

Comment: @Denis there is no new or additional information being stored in the blockchain.

Comment: there is too much information

Comment: What do you mean "too much information"? All of the data in blocks are necessary in order to properly verify blocks and transactions. There is neither too much nor too little.

Comment: I'am sorry, but you not a contributor of Bitcoin Core. How do you know that?

Comment: ??? I am a contributor to Bitcoin Core. Even so, you don't need to be one to understand how Bitcoin works.

Comment: sorry, bro *confused*

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage would be larger blocks, and thus more transactions included in each block. As more transactions are included in the block chain over an equal amount of time compared to the original chain, one would assume that fees would go down, since you would no longer have to worry about your transaction not getting included because the mempool is bloated.

The main disadvantages would be the rising cost to running a full node, which enforces the bitcoin protocol. If running a full node is only possible for a small amount of the users, those users are handed control over the other users.

Comment: `The main advantage would be larger blocks` you say. But larger blocks doesn't matter more transactions in block. And what abou the fees per `byte`?

Answer (score 0):

segwit2x is a proposal that bundles both the segregated witness technical change as a soft fork and a blocksize upgrade that takes place 3 months later.

the segregated witness part is complete and the bloclsize increase is scheduled for mid-november.

the benefits and drawbacks are subjective and controversial depending on who you ask.

segregated witness has benefits like allowing pruning of signatures and includes incentives to spend old dust transactions.

the block size increase has benefits in terms if more transaction capacity being available when it is needed.

both have drawbacks and neither have had enough time in the wild for all drawbacks to be known and are so far mostly speculative and politized.